# All borders or nothing - CSS

Tags: css

Whenever I try to set left and right border for an inline-block element in my code, it won't work unless I set all.

```
border:2px solid black; /* does work */
border:0 2px solid black; /* doesn't work*/
```

Any idea?

the relevant part of CSS:

```
#highlights2{
width:640px;
text-align:left;
}
#highlights2 .highlight{
width:211px;
display:inline-block;
height:100px;
background-color:#0dc1d0;
}

#centerhighlight{
border:0 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
border:2px solid black;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="highlights2"><div class="highlight">asd</div><div style="" class="highlight" id="centerhighlight">fgh</div><div class="highlight">jkl</div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using !important? Maybe another css property like (for example) .highlight{} has another css border property and you get a conflict. Or have you tried splitting the property in different ones? Like border-style, border-width, border-color...A good way to debug is always dividing the problem in smaller ones to check which one is working and which one is not.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is not valid for defining borders. If you want different styles for vertical and horizontal borders you need to write it longhand, for example:

```
border: 2px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 0;
```

Comment: Or even shorter: border-top: 0;

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff: This almost asks to be turned into a code golf... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the shorthand for border width, you can use this:

```
border-width:0 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpLvd/)